# Need of explanation for CAS along with spring security

Tags: spring-security, cas

1.In CAS architecture each client connecting to the CAS server based on different protocals(cas,oauth,SAML). is it providing a way to connect with different protocals or is it manadatory?
2.what is proxy authentication.how its work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using a CAS server, all integrated client apps should use the CAS protocol. Though, as the CAS supports OAuth, OpenID Connect, SAML, you can enable them on CAS server side and integrate client apps through various protocols.

When it comes to multiple protocols, I can only recommend using [pac4j](http://www.pac4j.org/) to make things easy: you can use it altogether with Spring Security: https://github.com/pac4j/spring-security-pac4j